# How to develope a server application using Google Analytics API?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api-client

I am developing a server side application to pull data from my Google Analytics account using php. I have registered my application in a Google API Console as a Service Application which gave me Client_Id and Private Key. I want to run this application using Terminal/Command Prompt. But I have read somewhere that most of Google API's do not support Service Account.

I can not figure out how to authenticate my Service Application within Google's PHP Client API.
Is there any other to create a Server Application for Google Analytics which I can run on my Terminal/Command Prompt?

Answer (score -1):

You can write a simple PHP Script doing all your work.

To run it in terminal just type: `php myFile.php`